# How to write testclass for vf lookup field

Tags: controller, lookup, code-coverage

Below is the VF controller and test class

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1">
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Employer Details" id="empDetails" columns="1" >
            <apex:inputField id="accountName" value="{!accRecords.Employer__c}">  
                <!--<apex:actionsupport event="onselect" action="{!readAddress}" reRender="pb1"/>-->
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{!objacc.BillingStreet}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!servObj.Ending_week_for_timesheet__c}" label="Week">
                <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!readAddress}" reRender="pb1"/>
            </apex:inputField>
            <!--<apex:commandButton action="{!readAddress}" value="Get Particepants"/>-->
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <html>
```

controller

```
public class EmploymentHoursController {

    public Employer_Participant__c accRecords{get; set;}
    public Account objacc{get;set;}
    public List<Employer_Participant__c> listOfEmployee {get; set;}
    public boolean showEmpData{get;set;}
    public list<ServiceWrapper> serviceList {get;set;}
    Public list<Service__c> servicelisttoUpdate;
    public List<String> headers { get; set; }
    public set<ServiceWrapper> finaserviceSet ;
    Date myDate {get;set;}
    public Date EndOfWeek{get;set;}
    public list<mainWrpClass> EmpServiceListMap {get;set;}
    public Service__c servObj {get;set;}
    public date startofweek;

    public EmploymentHoursController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        accRecords = new Employer_Participant__c();
        showEmpData = false;
        Employer_Participant__c empObj= new Employer_Participant__c();
        servObj = New Service__c();
        servObj.Ending_week_for_timesheet__c = system.today();
    }    
    public Date getEndOfWeek(){
        myDate = date.Today();
        EndOfWeek= myDate.toStartofWeek().addDays(6);
        system.debug('start date of week'+EndOfWeek);
        return EndOfWeek;
    }
    public List<string> finaldateList {get;set;}
    public void readAddress(){
        integer i;
        showEmpData = true;
        serviceList=new list<ServiceWrapper>();
        EmpServiceListMap= new list<mainWrpClass>();

        system.debug('selected acc id'+accRecords.Id);
        objacc=[select id, Name,BillingStreet from Account where id=:accRecords.Employer__c limit 1];
        system.debug('selected  accRecords.Employer__c'+accRecords.Employer__c);
        listOfEmployee   = new List<Employer_Participant__c>(); 
        listOfEmployee = [select id, Name, Contact_Person__r.Name , (Select id , Service_date__c , Hours__c, Employer_Participant__c from Services__r where Service_date__c != null),Date__c from Employer_Participant__c where Employer__c=:objacc.id ];
        system.debug('listOfEmployee ...'+listOfEmployee);
```

Test class

```
@IsTest
public class EmploymentHoursControllerTest {
    public Integer testint =8;
    public String teststr ='Monday';
    public  Date testdate  =date.today();
    public  Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount');

    public static testmethod void testemployee(){
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAccount', BillingStreet = 'New');
        //acc.BillingAddress='the test address';
        //Account.BillingPostalCode=413248;
        // Acc.BillingState='New y';
        // Acc.BillingCountry='America';
        // Acc.Phone='65465465';
        insert acc;

        Class_Workshop__c classObj= new Class_Workshop__c();
        classObj.name='Test class Name';
        insert classObj;

        Employer_Participant__c  empObj= new Employer_Participant__c();
         empObj.Employer__c=acc.id;
        empObj.Job_Fair__c=classObj.id;
        insert  empObj;

        service__c serObj= new service__c();
        serObj.Ending_week_for_timesheet__c=date.today();
        serObj.Service_Date__c= date.today();
        insert serObj;

        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.EmploymentHoursVF);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('acc',empObj.Employer__c);

        test.startTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(acc);        
        EmploymentHoursController EmploymentHoursControllerObj= new EmploymentHoursController(sc);
        EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper serviceWrapperObj= new  EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper(4,'Monday',Date.today(),empObj.id,serObj.id);
        EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper serviceWrapperObj1= new  EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper(4,'Monday',Date.today(),empObj.id,serObj.id);
        list<EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper> servicewrapperlist= new list<EmploymentHoursController.ServiceWrapper>();
        servicewrapperlist.add(serviceWrapperObj);
        servicewrapperlist.add(serviceWrapperObj1);
        EmploymentHoursController.mainWrpClass mainWrpClassObj= new  EmploymentHoursController.mainWrpClass(empObj,servicewrapperlist);
        EmploymentHoursControllerObj.getEndOfWeek();
        EmploymentHoursControllerObj.readAddress();

        //EmploymentHoursControllerObj.saveService();
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

`EmploymentHoursControllerObj.readAddress();`This line giving an error :

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

on `objacc=[select id, Name,BillingStreet from Account where id=:accRecords.Employer__c limit 1];`this line of controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set accRecords.Employer__c value from your test class.

before calling this method.
EmploymentHoursControllerObj.readAddress();

use :
EmploymentHoursControllerObj.Employer__c = 'Employer Id';
EmploymentHoursControllerObj.readAddress();

Hope this helps !!

Comment: it is giving me an error Variable does not exist: Employer__c

Comment: Please mark it as solution.